# Maven Tycho fails as it tries to unzip a signature file (tycho-packaging-plugin)

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, packaging, xtext, tycho

I am building an Xtext project with Maven+Tycho. `mvn clean install` completes successfully, `mvn deploy` completes successfully as well, but `mvn clean install deploy` fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:1.4.0:package-feature
(default-package-feature) on project protelis.parser.feature:
Execution default-package-feature of goal
org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:1.4.0:package-feature failed:
Could not determine installation size of file
/.../protelis.parser/target/protelis.parser-8.1.0.pom.asc:
error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
```

(newlines mine, to ease reading)

It looks to me that some plugin Maven is trying to use a signature file as if were a compressed zip file, and fails.
I probably can work this around by running `mvn clean install && mvn clean deploy`, but I'd like to investigate, understand the root cause, and fix this for good.

[Here](https://github.com/Protelis/Protelis-Parser/tree/41d2f779c530f602a02cba71356545eb7eeb5603) is a link to the failing project, for `pom.xml` inspection.